# How to reverse the keyframe once it's applied

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

Here is the animation I am using and the javascript code to add the corresponding classes when clicking on specific buttons. It works fine.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

 $('.show').on('click', () => {
   $('.child').addClass('show');
  })
  
  $('.hide').on('click', () => {
   $('.child').addClass('hide');
  })
  
})
```

```css
.child{
  width:0;
  height:0;
  border:2px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.child.show{
   animation-name: expandit;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
}

.child.hide{
   animation-name: hideit;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-direction: reverse;
}


@keyframes expandit {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes hideit {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <a class="show" href="#">Show</a>
  <a class="hide" href="#">Hide</a>
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Now user clicks on close button. I would like to revert back to width as `0` by using the keyframes. How can I do this?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `animation-fill-mode` property which allows you to keep the final state of the animation applied as [documented on w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp).

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $('.show').on('click', () => {
    $('.child').addClass('show');
  })

  $('.hide').on('click', () => {
    $('.child').addClass('hide');
  })

})
```

```css
.child {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child.show {
  animation-name: expandit;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child.hide {
  animation-name: hideit;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes expandit {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}

@keyframes hideit {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <a class="show" href="#">Show</a>
  <a class="hide" href="#">Hide</a>
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

However, if you would like to revert to the "real initial state" where `height: 0;`, it would require an additional keyframe at 99.99% to hide this second animation. Feel free to leave a comment if you have any follow-up questions.